# String index out of range, Python

Tags: python-3.x

code for a function which increments a string, to create a new string. If the string already ends with a number, the number should be incremented by 1. If the string does not end with a number the number 1 should be appended to the new string.

The output is correct but it is showing a `String index out of range` error. Can someone help me on where and how the string index is out of range?

test cases,expected output:
(increment_string("foo"), "foo1"),(increment_string("foobar001"), "foobar002"),(increment_string("foobar1"), "foobar2"),(increment_string("foobar00"), "foobar01"),("foobar99"), "foobar100"),("foobar099"), "foobar100"),(increment_string(""), "1")

```
def increment_string(strng):
   if strng[-1].isdigit():
      exp_strng=strng[::-1]
      new_strng=""
      new_strng1=""
      for i in exp_strng:
         if i.isdigit():
            new_strng+=i
         else:
            break
      new_strng=new_strng[::-1]
      new_strng1=int(new_strng)+1
      new_strng1='{num:{fill}{width}}'.format(num=new_strng1, fill='0', width=len(new_strng))
      return(strng[:-len(new_strng)]+new_strng1)

   else:
      strng+="1"
      return(strng)
```

Comment: Huh, I am not seeing the `string index out of range` error. Are you sure this is the entirety of your erroneous code?

Comment: You're passing a string into `new_strng1=int(new_strng)+1`. Did you mean `len(new_strng) + 1`?

Comment: no new_strng1 is to convert string to integer then adding 1 to it @Skam

Comment: @Jerrybibo it shows error in codewars website while submitting code. all outputs are passed though.

Comment: does it provide you with the input used? if we can't reproduce, then it's hard for us to help you. ¯\_(ツ)_/¯

Comment: @mob Consider an empty string as a possible (hidden) edge case. I'm not sure about whether codewars is mean enough to give you that though, but give it a shot.

Comment: @Skam no all inputs are passed succesfully but unable to complete task cause of index out of range

Comment: that means, what happens if your code is passed a `""` into it

Comment: @mob See? An edge case for an empty string (`""`).

Comment: @skam thanks yes it was the problem

Comment: @mob I submitted an answer based on your original code.

Answer (score 2):

If think this would be a better solution to your problem:

```
from re import search

def increment_string(s):
    number = search('\d+$', s)
    if number != None:
        number = number.group()
        first_part = s.split(number)[0]
        return first_part + str(int(number)+1)
    else:
        return s + '1'
```

I don't know what you want when the number is 9 though: 0 or 10. This code produces 10.

Comment: This does not solve the problem that OP has – the event in which an empty string `""` is given as the argument.

Comment: I've edited it and now it should work perfectly, sorry for the mess.

Answer (score 2):

Since you gave us more information on the test cases given, you can bypass the edge case of an empty string by modifying the `if` statement:

```
def increment_string(strng):
   # Add it here #
   if strng == "":
      return "1"

   elif strng[-1].isdigit():
      exp_strng = strng[::-1]
      new_strng = ""
      new_strng1 = ""
      for i in exp_strng:
         if i.isdigit():
            new_strng += i
         else:
            break
      new_strng = new_strng[::-1]
      new_strng1 = int(new_strng) + 1
      new_strng1 = '{num:{fill}{width}}'.format(num=new_strng1, fill='0', width=len(new_strng))
      return strng[:-len(new_strng)] + new_strng1

   else:
      strng += "1"
      return strng
```

Answer (score -1):

the error was caused when empty string is passed. and I resolved it by adding one more if else:(thanks to Skam)

```
def increment_string(strng):
if len(strng)>0:
    if strng[-1].isdigit():
        exp_strng=strng[::-1]
        new_strng=""
        new_strng=""
        for i in exp_strng:
            if i.isdigit():
                new_strng+=i
            else:
                break
        new_strng=new_strng[::-1]
        new_strng1=int(new_strng)+1
        new_strng1=str(new_strng1)
        new_strng1=new_strng1.zfill(len(new_strng))
        return(strng[:-len(new_strng)]+new_strng1)
    else:
        strng+="1"
        return(strng)
else:
    strng+="1"
    return(strng)
```